# Print / Fullscreen / Email icons

Tags: plone

In Plone 2, there were icons for print, fullscreen and email in object views.

How do I enable these in Plone 4?  They don't seem to be present in a default installation of Plone 4.1, but I must be missing something, and I'd like to know what?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, document actions can be re-enabled in Plone 4 in the ZMI interface for the actions tool: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/document-actions-in-plone-4-td5788892.html

- Go to ./manage_main for your Plone site.
- Click on portal_actions
- Click on document_actions
- Click on each action you want to make a visible link (print, rss, etc).
- Click "visible" checkbox, then save.

Comment: There, they do appear, thanks.  Fullscreen javascript ignores me when I click it, but that's another issue.

Comment: Note that 'Send this' no longer appears under document_actions in Plone 4, but you can restore it by manually adding a sendto CMF Action. The key properties to set are the URL expression (`string:$object_url/sendto_form`) and Permissions (Allow sendto).