# How do I get the "Print this" option on pages of Plone 4?

Tags: plone

Plone 3 basically gave users the choices "Send this" and "Print this" on every page. Plone 4 (at least my instance) only gives "Send this".  How do I enable/add/restore the "print this" option? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383098/print-fullscreen-email-icons

Answer (score 4):

"Print this" is an action. Go to *portal_actions -> document_actions -> print* in the ZMI and set *Visible?* to true.

You can use *actions.xml* to do the same thing through GenericSetup:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_actions" meta_type="Plone Actions Tool"
   xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n">
 <object name="document_actions" meta_type="CMF Action Category">
  <object name="print" meta_type="CMF Action" i18n:domain="plone">
   <property name="visible">True</property>
  </object>
 </object>
</object>
```

See more about actions and GenericSetup [here](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functionality/actions.html).

Comment: @Campbell Good point. Link (and example _actions.xml_) added.