# How to change url expression for 'Print this' document_action in Plone to be used with for collective.documentviewer?

Tags: javascript, python, plone, tesseract, zope

I am using Plone unified installer 4.1.4 and wish to change the URL Expression for the portal_actions, document_actions for 'Print this'. so that the same can be enabled for collective.documentviewer. I got this reference from [enter link description here][1][Print / Fullscreen / Email icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383098/print-fullscreen-email-icons)

Using this however only the contents of the current window are printed and not the contents of the file being displayed in the viewer. I am not good at javascript. If anyone could please revert with the javascipt expression, I will be grateful.

Note: I do not wish to download the file from document viewer by clicking the 'Original Document' as is the default behaviour of the viewer, but wish to print the contents of the file from the viewer directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the action expressions in Zope Management Interface under `portal_actions`.

It is not clear of the context if there is an URL directly leading to printing in collective.documentviewer. But as soon as you have such URL it is trivial to edit the print action to go to this URL.

Also if you want to keep the default printing action, you can add two print actions in `portal_actions` with different conditions, so that one is for non-collective-documentviewer content types and other is collective.documentviewer content types. You can construct an expression which separates content types by their interface.

More information about actions:

https://developer.plone.org/functionality/actions.html

More information about expressions to construct action URL:

https://developer.plone.org/functionality/expressions.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/315168/mikko-ohtamaa Thanks for the immediate response. I will try to learn how to construct the URL Expression (javascript). But I am in an urgency at the moment if anybody can help.

Comment: Unfortunately I have used collective.documentviewer, so I cannot know what kind of views (for printing) it has and cannot give detailed answer.